# How do I determine what shell a script was meant to use?

Tags: shell

I have this non-functioning script, before I can attempt to fix it I need to know what kind of shell this was supposed to run in.

```
#
set pwrs = ( 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
@ pwrs[1]=1
@ next=2
while ( $next < 9 )
        @ last = $next - 1
        @ pwrs[$next] = $pwrs[$last] * 2
        @ next = $next + 1
end

@count = 1
while ( $count <= 8 )
        echo $pwrs[$count]
        @ count = $count + 1
end
```

Comment: Interesting.  I don't recognize the language.  It isn't a C shell or Bourne shell derivative (not `bash`, `ksh`, `tcsh`, etc).  It isn't Perl or Python; I don't think it is Ruby either, though I'm not as sure of that.  It's not `awk`; it isn't Tcl/Tk.  Was it from a Windows machine?  If so, Powershell might be a possibility, but treat that with a huge pinch of salt; it is an almost wild (and mostly uninformed) guess.

Comment: This was in linux. The default shell used is tcsh but that clearly isn't it. I cp'ed this as is from somewhere. I swear it had no shebang. IDK maybe I could change the `@` to `$` and see if I can run it then

Comment: @shellter: The `@` symbols would be the first thing that don't look like C shell — but having gone to the (`tcsh`) manual I find that it is a C shell construct, so — while it looks like no C shell script I've seen before (though I've not studied many of them by conscious decision) — it may well be a C shell script.  See [`tcsh` manual](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html#@) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to produce appropriate output using `csh`. I would expect `tcsh` to work as well.

Turns out I do have a csh available. I pasted the code into the cmdline.

There was one error. All math calculations that begin with the `@` char must be separated from their following variable name, hence

```
@count = 1
```

Needed to be fixed as

```
@ count = 1

$ set pwrs = ( 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
$ @ pwrs[1]=1
$ @ next=2
$ while ( $next < 9 )
while?         @ last = $next - 1
while?         @ pwrs[$next] = $pwrs[$last] * 2
while?         @ next = $next + 1
while? end

$ @ count = 1
$ while ( $count <= 8 )
while?         echo $pwrs[$count]
while?         @ count = $count + 1
while? end
```

**output**

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
[oracle@localhost ~]$
```

See [Grymoire Unix - Csh](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html)  for explanation of the csh `@`, and `$pwrs[$next]` (array notation). Your specific case is not addressed, but you should be able to work it out. If you have other questions after you build small test cases that don't work, post them with sample inputs, expected outputs,  and your current code and output.

Also, don't spend any more time on csh, while not as bad as some portray it, you will ultimately discover that there are problems you can't solve in csh. All of it's nice cmd-line features are included in bash, so you might want to consider using it.Finally, see [Grymoire csh top 10](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt)  for detailed reasons why you want to convert this code to a newer shell.

IHTH